# Help in understanding how this over-voltage regulator works

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, comparator

I found a circuit on the internet that's using a comparator to solve a similar problem to one I'm hoping to solve (voltage regulation).

This is the circuit: (it's from https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa20/snoaa20.pdf)

[image]

I understand that the voltage divider at the input is taking a 1/3 of the input voltage and comparing to the reference voltage of 10V - if \$V{in}>V_{ref}\$ then the voltage exceeds 30V (stipulated max \$V_{in}\$) and the regulator would send \$V_{OH}\$ to \$V_g\$ (which would be supply V). Otherwise the comparator would output \$V_{OL}\$ (near 0V). I understand also that the Zener diode connecting the Source and Gate at the Mosfet (\$Z_2\$) is putting the Mosfet in a default ON state (sets \$V_{gs}=16V<20V\$ (\$V_{gs(max)}=20V\$).

What I don't understand is how feeding back the supply voltage to the Gate (\$V_{OH}\$) is going to turn the gate OFF.

E.g. at 32V Supply > Load Tolerance \$\implies\$ \$V_{OH}=32V \implies V_g~=32-16+32=48V\$
But then \$V_{gs}=|48-32|=16V<V_{gs(max)}=20V \implies\$ Mosfet=ON?

If anyone can help me understand where I'm going wrong (presumably something simple) I would greatly appreciate it. I don't have a massive amount of experience with mosfets and essentially none with comparators.

Comment: The zener's only purpose is to prevent the MOSFET's Vgs-max limit being exceeded when the opamp's output goes low with a high input voltage. Without the zener the full input voltage would be applied between the gate and source.

Comment: I'm also not entirely clear on your use of "open" and "close" here. Does "open" mean an open door allowing passage through, or does open mean open circuit where current does not flow.

Comment: @brhans - I just edited the OP to reflect by "open" I meant ON and "closed" I meant OFF

Comment: @brhans - are you able help me understand how the comparator is putting the MOSFET into an OFF state when it exceeds the reference voltage?

Comment: Note that the MOSFET is a P-channel type. The MOSFET will conduct when the gate is more negative than the incoming supply rail or will not conduct when the gate voltage is close to the supply input.

Comment: @KevinWhite - thanks. But if threshold Vgs = 20V, doesn't that mean the gate will only be off if the difference exceeds 20V?

Comment: @p.chives VgsMax is *not* the threshold voltage - it's the gate-source voltage at which the MOSFET is no longer guaranteed to survive. The threshold is much smaller, on the order of a few volts.

Comment: @nanofarad - thanks! How do I know what voltage differences will turn a MOSFET (p-type) ON/OFF? Is it labelled in the datasheet?

Comment: It isn't  specific voltage. There is a threshold voltage at which it will just start turning on and there will be a graph of voltage vs on resistance or voltage vs drain current that can be used to determine how much voltage is needed for a particular current. Most power MOSFETs will be specified at something like 4.5V or 10V gate bias to be "fully on" depending upon type.